# Wireshark network layer name resolution pcap

Tags: dns, wireshark, pcap

I'm interested in saving a pcap that has network layer name resolution. While it works great within Wireshark, how can I save it with the resolved names intact? Having this information would be extremely helpful for me and save me a lot of time if this is possible. I understand in the documentation that it can't be saved within the pcap file (http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvNameResolutionSection.html#idp390072124) but is there an alternative way to do so? Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but in theory the name resolution information can/will be stored in the [pcap-ng file format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/PcapNg), which has been Wireshark's default file format since version 1.8.  The old pcap file format you cite won't, but pcap-ng has a specific defined block type in its format for ip<->name resolution information.

Comment: Wireshark's support for the name resolution block has historically been rather flaky -- its original architecture didn't mesh well with special pcap-ng blocks in general -- but it should work as advertised in recent versions (1.10 and later).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like as long as you open the file with the "Network name resolution" checkbox checked, it should resolve the IPs no problem. The version of Wireshark that I have automatically saves them as .pcapng already.